# Not able to login with "requests" module

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I'm trying to log into a website with the requests module.

```
import requests

url = "http://m.kicktipp.de/info/profil/login"
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.get(url)
    payload = {"kennung": "my_email", "passwort": "my_password"}
    s.post(url, data=payload)
    r = s.get(url)
    print(r.text)
```

After running the code I checked the html-code ouput and noticed that 
the login failed. The keys seem to be correct ("kennung", "passwort"). There aren't any middlewaretokens neither which could cause any trouble.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: you might want to try using RoboBrowser: https://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/readme.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tried using RoboBrowser and it works flawlessly. Guess my problem is solved for now. Though, I'm still wondering why my "requests approach" didn't work.